# Validate json single object by passing two different values with same property using underscore.js

Tags: underscore.js

Passing one json object everytime but role values changing and i need to validate it based on role using `_.findWhere` object using one value but i want validate with two different roles in same property.

Scenario 1

```
var people = [ 
            {"name": "ram", "RoleID": "2"}
        ];
var roleObj = _.findWhere(people , { RoleID: "2", RoleID: "4"});
```

Scenario 2

```
var people = [ 
            {"name": "ram", "RoleID": "3"}
        ];
var roleObj = _.findWhere(people , { RoleID: "2", RoleID: "4"});
```

In scenario 2 i should not get object why because in scound parameter not having role 3. could you please tell which _.js object i can use or what i need to change input 2nd parameter

Note: this question is scenario of `in` operator in sql server where we can pass multiple values in single column.

Comment: Should `RoleId` by `role`? You cannot match on both using `findWhere`, I'll add an answer which doesn't need underscore

Comment: Sorry modified question by RoleID.

Comment: I've updated my answer to cover `RoleId`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without `underscore` by using `filter`. Simply filter out those people whose role does not appear in the list of roles specified:

```js
var people = [{
  "name": "ram",
  "RoleId": "3"
}];

var peopleTwo = [{
  "name": "ram",
  "RoleId": "2"
}];

var getRoleFilterer = roles =>
  people =>
    people.filter(person => roles.indexOf(person.RoleId) > -1);

var roleFilterer = getRoleFilterer(["2", "4"]);

var results = roleFilterer(people);
var resultsTwo = roleFilterer(peopleTwo);

console.dir(results);
console.dir(resultsTwo);
```

Comment: Awesome solution, but I'm looking to solve by Underscore. is it not possible with it?

Comment: @lucky why do you want to use Underscore when it's possible in vanilla js?

Comment: This application is developing using asp.net with jquery only, me only introduced underscorejs in this app.

Comment: @lucky Sure - but why do you want to use underscore here? You don't need any libraries to use the code in my snippet